# Restoring quick response icon of documents

Tags: 16.04, icons, home-directory

I accidentally deleted my documents folder. I managed to restored it and to to find the original folder icon. But the quick response icon of documents underneath the icon of home on the column of the left side of folder manager (when we open any folder) is gone. I want to restore this icon-link, please. Ubuntu 16.04.

[image]

Comment: Try dragging the `Documents` folder into a blank part of the quick launch area and adding a link to it there. Then, try restarting your computer. Does that fix it?

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it doesn't work. Dragging just cuts and pastes documents on another folder like music, videos etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try editing the file `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` and adding the Documents menu back in.
Here's mine:

```
# This file is written by xdg-user-dirs-update
# If you want to change or add directories, just edit the line you're
# interested in. All local changes will be retained on the next run
# Format is XDG_xxx_DIR="$HOME/yyy", where yyy is a shell-escaped
# homedir-relative path, or XDG_xxx_DIR="/yyy", where /yyy is an
# absolute path. No other format is supported.
# 
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your interest! It worked! Have a nice day!

Comment: @keram Hi Keram, if this answer has worked for you, kindly consider accepting it by clicking on the tick. I wouldn't also mind an upvote :)